# Selecting an element by className from a jsx file in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I had an older project (image slide) with "JS, Html and CSS" and I'm new to React.
I wanted to know if I can use my existing JS script to recreate the project without rewriting it in jsx?
I already have tried to implement my JS script into a react component like bellow:

```
import ny from './images/ny.jpg'
import ny1 from './images/ny1.jpg'
import ny2 from './images/ny2.jpg'
import ny3 from './images/ny3.jpg'
import ny4 from './images/ny4.jpg'
import nextBtn from './images/nextBtn.svg'
import prevBtn from './images/prevBtn.svg'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = "./script/script.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="carousel-container">
      <div className="carousel-slide">
        <img src={ny4} alt="" id="last-clone"/>
        <img src={ny} alt="" />
        <img src={ny1} alt="" />
        <img src={ny2} alt="" />
        <img src={ny3} alt="" />
        <img src={ny4} alt="" />
        <img src={ny} alt="" id="first-clone"/>
      </div>
      <button id="next-btn">
        <img src={prevBtn} alt="" />
      </button>
      <button id="pre-btn">
        <img src={nextBtn} alt="" />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

But it throws an ERROR:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I know the problem is that the JS script can query the element from jsx with it's className.

This is my vanilla JS:

```
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImage = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');

const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#pre-btn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#next-btn');

let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImage[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (counter >= carouselImage.length - 1) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = 'transform 0.8s ease-in-out';
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (counter <= 0) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = 'transform 0.4s ease-in-out';
    counter--;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});

carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    if (carouselImage[counter].id === 'last-clone') {
        //you can delete this line to see the effect
        carouselSlide.style.transition = 'none'; 
        counter = carouselImage.length - 2;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    }
    if (carouselImage[counter].id === 'first-clone') {
        //you can delete this line to see the effect
        carouselSlide.style.transition = 'none'; 
        counter = carouselImage.length - counter;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    }
})
```

And here is the react App.js :

```
import './App.css';
import helmet, { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import MyComponent from './component'

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <MyComponent/>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And also I think there is something wrong with my image loading, correct me if it's wrong.

Tried to use old image carousel JS script in React and it back fired.

Comment: What exactly does "script.js" look like?

Comment: i'm not sure but i think you should include it in the index.html file like so 
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>

Comment: @Pointy I uploaded the Vanilla JS in my question after the ERROR .
Forgot to mention that it's my script!